# SSH - UsePAM yes or no?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

After setting up SSH key-based authentication, people are advised to disable SSH password authentication.

This is done by navigating to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and making sure that the following line is not commented out:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Some tutorials, e.g.

- [How to Set Up SSH Keys on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-1804/)

recommend also setting

```
UsePAM no
```

After doing that, I have noticed that I no longer get session notifications from the host. For example when I want to shutdown/reboot it, the terminal hangs and I no longer get:

```
Connection to 192.168.0.3 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.0.3 closed.
```

I have read [here](https://serverfault.com/a/669464/583444) that one should "probably want to keep it on". Furthermore it may actually help you get safer.

**Questions**:

1. How precisely does `UsePAM no` contribute to security?
2. Can I somehow still get the session status if I disable `UsePAM`?

Answer (score 2):

I copy past the comment in the default confiugration file

> Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
> and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
> be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
> PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
> PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
> the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
> If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
> PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
> and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.

for those reason disabling only PasswordAuthentication and ChallengeResponseAuthentication let pam to be setup to handle account and session staff
I copy past what those modules type are meant for

> account
>
> this module type performs non-authentication based account management. It is typically used to restrict/permit access to a
> service based on the time of day, currently available system resources
> (maximum number of users) or perhaps the location of the applicant
> user -- 'root' login only on the console.
>
> session
>
> this module type is associated with doing things that need to be done for the user before/after they can be given service. Such things
> include the logging of information concerning the opening/closing of
> some data exchange with a user, mounting directories, etc.

you could check the pamd configuration file in etc/pam.conf etc/pam.d/*
and doucle check what modules do.
Furthermore the connection termination message does not seem to be related to pam configuration...
it's sent by sshd specifically in clientloop.c function client_loop

```
         /*
          * In interactive mode (with pseudo tty) display a message indicating
          * that the connection has been closed.
          */
         if (have_pty && options.log_level != SYSLOG_LEVEL_QUIET) {
                 if ((r = sshbuf_putf(stderr_buffer,
                     "Connection to %.64s closed.\r\n", host)) != 0)
                         fatal("%s: buffer error: %s", __func__, ssh_err(r));
         }
```

in my case it prints that message no matter the value of UsePAM.